# How does CSS font-weight work with emojis?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm blocked by a question, on some Android device, I type some emoji and save them to database.
Then load them and display in html page, but the emoji is invisible if set a `font-weight: bold`.
If set `font-weight: normal` can display.

How does css font-weight work?
How does the browser parse CSS when it sees `font-weight:bold` or `font-weight:normal`?

Comment: Are you asking the general question in the title, which is probably too broad and probably off-topic at SO, or a practical question about using bold face for some characters? In the latter case, please provide a testable case, with HTML code, CSS code, and information about the font used (origin, methods of creating the font files).

Answer (score 1):

System will call a bold font file (e.g., see [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts) which will list different weights of a font family) and if you don't have that font file on your device, it will fail to display the characters (actually for regular characters system tend to load a similar font in this case, but emoji characters are not regular).

You can include webfonts and contain the bold family in `<head>` section. E.g.,

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Browsers generally use “faux bold”, algorithmically bolding a regular font, when a bold typeface is not available.

Comment: what is browser behavior if a emoji bold typeface not available? Use a space?